# How to create a Record on Junction Object Using Apex?

Tags: apex, dml

Could anyone please tell me apex code for server side contoller about how to create a record on Junction Object(Detail side of Master Detail Relationship).
Say There are two objects Products__c and ProductGroup__c which are having many to many Master Detail Relationship using a Junction Object( Junction__c ).
From my Client Side Controller I am getting a list of Id's(listToAdd)from Products.
The Id of Group should be captured from URL of lightning component.(please tell how to achieve this too)
What I want to do is that Create a record on Junction__c populating the Id's from Group and Products (M-D relationship).

Thanks!!
My Client Side Contoller :-

```
   checkboxSelect: function(component, event, helper) {
  // get the selected checkbox value  
  var selectedRec = event.getSource().get("v.value");
  // get the selectedCount attrbute value(default is 0) for add/less numbers. 
  var getSelectedNumber = component.get("v.selectedCount");
  // check, if selected checkbox value is true then increment getSelectedNumber with 1 
  // else Decrement the getSelectedNumber with 1     
  if (selectedRec == true) {
   getSelectedNumber++;
  } else {
   getSelectedNumber--;
  }
  // set the actual value on selectedCount attribute to show on header part. 
  component.set("v.selectedCount", getSelectedNumber);
 },


    // For select all Checkboxes 
    selectAll: function(component, event, helper) {
        //get the header checkbox value  
        var selectedHeaderCheck = event.getSource().get("v.value");
        // get all checkbox on table with "boxPack" aura id (all iterate value have same Id)
        // return the List of all checkboxs element 
        var getAllId = component.find("boxPack");
        // If the local ID is unique[in single record case], find() returns the component. not array   
        if(! Array.isArray(getAllId)){
            if(selectedHeaderCheck == true){ 
                component.find("boxPack").set("v.value", true);
                component.set("v.selectedCount", 1);
            }else{
                component.find("boxPack").set("v.value", false);
                component.set("v.selectedCount", 0);
            }
        }else{
            // check if select all (header checkbox) is true then true all checkboxes on table in a for loop  
            // and set the all selected checkbox length in selectedCount attribute.
            // if value is false then make all checkboxes false in else part with play for loop 
            // and select count as 0 
            if (selectedHeaderCheck == true) {
                for (var i = 0; i < getAllId.length; i++) {
                    component.find("boxPack")[i].set("v.value", true);
                    component.set("v.selectedCount", getAllId.length);
                }
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < getAllId.length; i++) {
                    component.find("boxPack")[i].set("v.value", false);
                    component.set("v.selectedCount", 0);
                }
            } 
        }  

    },


 //For Adding selected records 
 addSelected: function(component, event, helper) {
  // create var for store record id's for selected checkboxes  
  var addId = [];
  // get all checkboxes 
  var getAllId = component.find("boxPack");
  // If the local ID is unique[in single record case], find() returns the component. not array
     if(! Array.isArray(getAllId)){
         if (getAllId.get("v.value") == true) {
           addId.push(getAllId.get("v.text"));
         }
     }else{
     // play a for loop and check every checkbox values 
     // if value is checked(true) then add those Id (store in Text attribute on checkbox) in addId var.
     for (var i = 0; i < getAllId.length; i++) {
       if (getAllId[i].get("v.value") == true) {
         addId.push(getAllId[i].get("v.text"));
       }
      }
     } 

     // call the helper function and pass all selected record id's.    
      helper.addSelectedHelper(component, event, delId);

 },
```

What I tried :-

```
public with sharing class UpdateWithCheckboxController {

 @AuraEnabled
 public static list < Products__c > fetchPDCN() {
  list < Products__c > returnPDList = new List < Products__c > ();

  List < Products__c > lstP = [SELECT Id,Name,Brand_Trademark_Name__c FROM Products__c LIMIT 50];
  // play for loop on lstP and add each contact to returnPDList List.
  for (Products__c c: lstP) {
   returnPDList.add(c);
  }
 // return the List of PDCN
  return returnPDList;
 }


 @AuraEnabled
 public static List < String > updateRecords(List < String > lstRecordId) {
// for store Error Messages  
    List < String > oErrorMsg = new List < String > ();
// Query Records to add where id in lstRecordId [which is pass from client side controller] 
    List < Products__c > lstUpdateRec = [select Id from Products__c where id IN: lstRecordId];
    return lstRecordId;
    /*List< Junction__c > recToAdd = new List< Junction__c >();
     recToAdd.Product__c = lstUpdateRec;
     recToAdd.Group__c = ;*/

 }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear from your code, but the list of ids that  you are passing to the apex controller contains just the ids of Product__c or ProductGroup__c or both?

Comment: ProductGroup__c id should be from URL . Sorry, I edited the question for this.

Answer (score 1):

To capture the `ProductGroup__c` Id from the url, include the following attribute in your Lightning component

`<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>`

which will by default have the value of the record Id on whose detail page the component is placed.

To pass values from lightning component to apex controller:

`var action = component.get( 'c.createJunction' );
action.setParams({
    groupId: component.get( 'v.recordId' ),
    prodIdList: component.get( 'v.prodIdList' )
});
$A.enqueueAction( action );`

For the apex controller, you could try something like

`@AuraEnabled
public static createJunction( String groupId, List<String> prodIdList ) {
    List<Junction__c> junctionList = new List<Junction__c>();
        for( String prodId : prodIdList ) {
            junctionList.add( new Junction__c( Product__c = prodId, ProductGroup__c = groupId ));
    }
    insert junctionList;
}`

Please make sure the master-detail parent field API names are correct.

Let me know if this works.